# "The plane is standing/resting/staying/sitting on the ground." What is the right word?

Tags: word-usage

Regarding the plane in the picture. What word should I use:

> The plane is/was **standing/resting/staying/sitting/*something else*** on the ground.

[image]

Comment: To describe that picture, I would just say, "The plane is on the ground." If you really must explicitly specify there is no ground motion, "resting" sounds best to me of those choices.

Comment: Perhaps, "parked on the ground" to note that it is turned off and stationary.

Answer (score 2):

In aviation terminology, you say "The plane is on the ground".

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I would describe the pilot standing next to the plane as *resting*. E.g

> I can see an old black and white photo of a pilot (who is) **resting against** a single-seat plane **on** the ground.

If you also wanted to describe the aircraft itself in the picture, you could call it a **[monoplane](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/monoplane)** because it has  a single main wing, and a single seat.

**EDIT**
If the OP's request was prompted by a multiple test question, then *standing* would be the next best option; e.g. *“The plane is/was standing on the ground”*

> **[stand](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stand?s=t)**
>   9. (**of things**) to be in an upright or vertical position, be set on end, or **rest on** or as on a support.

While **resting**  is also a possibility, it would suggest that the aircraft had recently landed and was expected to take off sometime soon.